# Mix of both POINT and LINESTRING objects in PostgreSQL column. How to extract both the POINT and first point out of the LINESTRING?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

So I have a column in a PostgreSQL database that contains both POINT objects and LINESTRING objects. Now my eventual goal is to extract both a latitude and longitude out of these objects. For POINT objects, this I can simply do by querying:

```sql
SELECT ST_X(records.primary_location) AS latitude,
       ST_Y(records.primary_location) AS longitude
FROM records
```

Now this would get me al latitudes and longitudes if it was just POINT objects in the database. 
However, there is also LINESTRINGs. From these I want to extract the first point and then retrieve the latitude and longitude for each of these points. To achieve getting both lat/longs from POINTS and LINESTRING, I tried:

```sql
SELECT ST_X(ST_PointN(records.primary_location, 1)) AS latitude,
       ST_Y(ST_PointN(records.primary_location, 1)) AS longitude
FROM records
```

In which I assumed that `ST_PointN()` would extract the first point from the LINESTRING and just keep one point from the POINT object. However, this does not work.

Does anybody have any clue how I can simultaneously retrieve lat/long coordinates out of these two types of objects in one column? Also, I would prefer this to happen with one query.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried embedding these conditions in a [`CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) expression based on the result of [`ST_GeometryType`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeometryType.html)?

Data sample

```
CREATE TABLE t (geom GEOMETRY);
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('POINT(1 1)'),
                     ('LINESTRING (8 1, 1 3, 4 4)'),
                     ('POINT(8 2)'),
                     ('LINESTRING (4 2, 2 4, 5 5)');
```

Query

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN ST_GeometryType(geom) = 'ST_Point' 
      THEN ST_AsText(geom)
    WHEN ST_GeometryType(geom) = 'ST_LineString' 
      THEN ST_AsText(ST_PointN(geom,1))
  END
FROM t;

    case    
------------
 POINT(1 1)
 POINT(8 1)
 POINT(8 2)
 POINT(4 2)
(4 Zeilen)
```

You can make it even simpler if you're sure there is no other geometry type in the column other than point and linestring

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN ST_GeometryType(geom) = 'ST_LineString' 
      THEN ST_AsText(ST_PointN(geom,1))
    ELSE ST_AsText(geom)
  END
FROM t;

 st_astext  
------------
 POINT(1 1)
 POINT(8 1)
 POINT(8 2)
 POINT(4 2)
(4 Zeilen)
```